# Guardar o valor de checkbox na base de dados

Tags: php, html, jquery

Preciso de uma ajuda vossa... Tenho um checkbox personalizado, onde o usuario clica e fica "ON" ou "OFF" e esse valor deve ser gravado no banco de dados e deve permanecer checked ou unchecked indicado pelo funicionário porque através desta o admin vai saber sê o funcionário está ON (no trabalho ou não) ou OFF. Acontece que ele não faz nada, não grava nada no banco de dados e não mostra nada no console do browser.

Segue o codigo em HTML

```
<form id="checkboxs_data" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" >
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" id="checkboxs">
    <input type="hidden" name="checkbox_offon" id="checkbox_offon" value="Off"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="nome_offon" value="<?php echo $row_func['nome'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_offon" value="<?php echo $row_func['id'];?>" />


<button type="submit" name="actionhCeckbox" id="actionCheckbox" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span> 
</button></form>
```

O input é recebido pelo jQuery:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#checkboxs').checkboxpicker({
                onLabel: 'On',
                offLabel: 'Off'
            });

            $('#checkboxs').change(function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked'))
                  {
                   $('#checkbox_offon').val('Off');
                  }
                else
                  {
                   $('#checkbox_offon').val('On');
                  }
            });

            $('#checkboxs_data').on('submit', function(e){

                e.preventDefault();
                var form_data = jQuery(this).serialize();


                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:"checkboxs.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:form_data,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#checkboxs_data')[0].reset();
                        $('#checkboxs').checkboxpicker('On');
                       setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = ""; }, 1000); 
                    }
                });
             });


        });
    </script>
```

E depois por sua vez o PHP recebe o formulário e faz a gravação na base de dados

```
<?php 
   $panel_atual = "funcionario";  $data = date("d-m-Y H:s");

$id_offon = $_POST["id_offon"]; 
$nome_offon = $_POST["nome_offon"];
$checkbox_offon = $_POST["checkbox_offon"];

$connect = "UPDATE funcionarios SET offon = '$checkbox_offon' ,  data = 
'$data' WHERE id = '$id_offon'";
$query = mysqli_query($conexao, $connect) ;

if($query)
{
  echo "<script laguange='javascript'> window.alert('done');</script>";
}else{echo "<script laguange='javascript'> window.alert('error'); 
 </script>";}

?>
```

Este é o botão checkbox com bootstrap:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: $.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .success(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });

Comment: ja ia fala dessas aspas manda muito elas

Comment: if($query){
echo json_encode(["msg" => 'parabens salvo com sucesso',"data" => 0]);
}else{
echo json_encode(["msg" => 'erro não foi salvo',"data" => 0]);
}

Comment: Ohh pah... esqueci de colocar a conexao que vem do config require "../config.php";

Comment: Más mesmo assim não funciona... Desculpem não percebi muito bem onde o @dvd diz para retirar o if(jQuery)

Comment: eu ja refiz a resposta pra vc a 4 coment pra cima @JosePinto

Comment: Já estava no codigo... ao postar me esqueci de coloca-lo

Comment: Apaguem os comentário passados!

Comment: Vou verificar aqui... Muito obrigado pela ajuda pessoal... Caso não conseguir retorno

Comment: Oi, Pessoal! Consegui faze-lo conforme voces falaram pelo codigo $('#checkboxs_data').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();     
      $.post( "checkboxs.php", $( "#checkboxs_data" ).serialize() )
 .done(function(response) {$('#checkboxs').checkboxpicker('On'); swal('Alterações salvas', response.message, response.status);
   });
 });

Comment: Más como posso manter o "Checkbox"  On...Porque quando faço o refresh da pagina ele volta para o off.. tentei usar o "if" buscando valor na base de dados por ex. se tiver escrito On ele mantem o Input com checked caso contrario mantem como unchecked mesmo assim nao funcionou... Podem me ajudar, por favor?